# compilation class and run-time class in Generics

Tags: java, generics

From my textbook I have the following example:

```
class A { public int val = 0; }
class B extends A { }
class Wrapper<T extends A> {
    public void wrapG(T t){a.val++; g(t); print(a.val); }
    private void g(A a) { print("g(A)"); }
    private void g(B c) { print("g(B)"); }
    static private A a = new A();
}
```

And the following main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wrapper<A> wa = new Wrapper<A>();
    Wrapper<B> wb = new Wrapper<B>();
    wa.wrapG(wa);
    wa.wrapG(wb);
    wb.wrapG(wb);
}
```

The output is: `g(A)1g(A)2g(A)3` (Assume that `print` is printing to the stdout).
I do understand why it prints `1,2,3` for the `val` (generics share static variables). But I don't understand why for `wb.wrapG(wb);` it prints `g(A)` and not `g(B)`. In compilation time, the static type of `wb` is `Wrapper<B>` and not `Wrapper<A>` so should call  `wrapG(B a)` and then `g(B)` and not `g(A)`. Why it prints `g(A)`? Is it because we have only one compilation/run-time class?

Comment: Compiler error: You're passing `Wrapper`s to a method that expects a `T` with an upper bound of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you have a compiler error.

I ran your example like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper<A> wa = new Wrapper<>();
        Wrapper<B> wb = new Wrapper<>();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        wa.wrapG(a);
        wa.wrapG(a);
        wb.wrapG(b);
    }
```

and the answer is because here:

```
class Wrapper<T extends A>
```

you say that `T` extends `A` so like `B` is also an `A` it call the first method and prints `"g(A)"`

Answer (score 0):

Damián Rafael Lattenero is right, but I think I might be able to improve on his explanation.

The key to understand is that the method `g` is overloaded and the correct overloaded method to call is decided at compile time.

Since `t` is of type `T` and `T` extends `A` the compiler can guarantee that `g(A a)` is a valid call target, so it is chosen.

The fact that `t` is actually an instance of `B` is only known at runtime and is therefore not considered for picking the right method `g` to invoke.

Note that this is different from inheritance and overwriting.
imagine both classes `A` and `B` had a method `void f()` that gets invoked inside `wrapG`. Dispatching to the right overwritten method happens at runtime and different implementations of `f` would get invoked depending on which variable (`a` or `b`) gets passed in.